# Laravel mass assignment won't fill fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mass-assignment

I have a model that doesn't seem to be mass assignable, even though I have filled in the `$fillable` fields:

```
class LoginAttempt extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'login_history';
    protected $fillable = array('remote_addr', 'user_agent', 'successful');

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Which is using this schema:

- login_history

  - id
  - user_id
  - remote_addr
  - user_agent
  - successful
  - created_at
  - updated_at

When I mass assign the instance with these variables,

```
$vars = array(
    'remote_addr' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'user_agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    'successful' => false,
);

print_r($vars);
=> array('remote_addr' => '127.0.0.1', 'user_agent' => 'Moz..', 'successful' => false);

new LoginAttempt($vars);
=> LoginAttempt instance, attributes => array()

LoginAttempt::create($vars);
=> LoginAttempt instance, attributes => array()

$login = new LoginAttempt;
$login->fill($vars);
=> LoginAttempt instance, attributes => array()

$login = new LoginAttempt;
$login->remote_addr = $vars['remote_addr'];
$login->user_agent= $vars['user_agent'];
$login->successful= $vars['successful'];
=> LoginAttempt instance, attributes => array('remote_addr' => '..', 'user_agent' => '..', 'successful' => false)
```

I think I'm using `$fillable` as the docs describe - why isn't mass assignment working in this case?

Comment: Thanks for this great example of working code. :)

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this was [a bug](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1548) in Laravel (has been [fixed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/3ceb8193a69a99e7c08750bed66482b786333820)) - all fields are guarded by default (`protected $guarded = array('*');`) which then took precedence over `$fillable`.