# Laravel Eloquent queries modification

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my application I have three tables: question, category and theme. When I add a question I choose a category, it adds the name of the category and the name of the theme.

I've tried this way; it worked, but I don't think it's the best way.

```
public function store() 
{
    $category = Input::get('category');

    $categoryName = DB::table('category')
            ->where('categoryId', 'LIKE', $category)
            ->pluck('categoryName');

    $themeId = DB::table('category')
            ->where('categoryId', 'LIKE', $category)
            ->pluck('themeId');

    $themeName = DB::table('theme')
            ->where('themeId', 'LIKE', $themeId)
            ->pluck('themeName');


    $question = new questionList;

    $question->questionId = Input::get('questionId');
    $question->question = Input::get('question');
    $question->rightAnswer = Input::get('rightAnswer');
    $question->explanation = Input::get('explanation');
    $question->wrongAnswer1 = Input::get('wrongAnswer1');
    $question->wrongAnswer2 = Input::get('wrongAnswer2');
    $question->wrongAnswer3 = Input::get('wrongAnswer3');
    $question->theme = $themeName;
    $question->category = $categoryName;
    $question->difficulty = Input::get('difficulty');

    $question->save();

    if ($question->save()) 
    {
        return Response::json(array(
                'status' => 'ok',
                'message' => 'success',
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: remove $question->save(); if($question->save()) should do the job.

Comment: im talking about the 3 queries in the top !!

Comment: for that i would either use eloquent models created for them or repos created for them,

Comment: how can i use them !! thx

Comment: Creating model for category and calling Category::where('your where')->first() (i think) and for your $question search for laravel mass assignment like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965226/laravel-mass-assignment-wont-fill-fields

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking if it's OK to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
$category = DB::table('category')
 ->where('categoryId','LIKE',$category)
 ->first();

$categoryName = $category->name;
$themeId      = $category->themeId;
$themeName    = $category->themeName;
```